# Consumer problem

Tags: microeconomics

In the basic problem of consumer's choice the budget set $B(p,w)$, with $p$ the vector of prices belonging to $\mathbb{R}^N_{++}$ and $w >0$ wealth, define a convex set. Following from that I don't understand why this implies that if the utility function $U: X \to \mathbb{R}$  is strictly concave, then the solution $x^*(p,w)$ is unique for each $(p,w)>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We consider the following problem:
$$
\max_{x} u(x) \text{ s.t. } p'x \le w.
$$
Let us show that if $u$ is strictly concave, then the solution (if it exists) is unique.

We proof by contradiction. Assume that the solution is not unique. Then there should exist at least two solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$. As both bundles are optimal, they should give the same utility, so $u(x_1) = u(x_2)$.

Also, both of these bundles should be in the budget constraint: $p' x_1 \le w$ and $p' x_2 \le w$.

Now, take any strict convex combination of these two bundles, say $\widetilde{x} = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}$. As the budget set is convex, we have that $p' \widetilde{x} = \frac{1}{2} p'x_1 + \frac{1}{2} p'x_2 \le w$, so the bundle $\widetilde{x}$ is also in the budget set.

But now, by strict concavity of $u$, we have that:
$$
u(\widetilde{x}) = u(\frac{1}{2}x_1 + \frac{1}{2} x_2) > \frac{1}{2}u(x_1) + \frac{1}{2} u(x_2) = u(x_1).
$$
(the last equality follows as $u(x_1) = u(x_2)$). However, this is impossible as $x_1$ was optimal (i.e. gives the highest utility for all bundles in the budget set).

Comment: Thanks a lot, clear answer !